# Read data from a raid1 disk, superblocks erased

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery, mdadm

I have a disk that used to be inside my qnap NAS (it was in raid1 with another disk, which I still have). The NAS died and I mounted the disk on my ubuntu machine using `mdadm` to create the raid array and then followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member) to successfully mount and read it.

Then I shut down the laptop and when I turned it back on I couldn't mount anything (mdadm was returning errors saying devices were busy). I tried a bunch of stuff (rebooting as well) but couldn't mount it back.

Out of frustration I had the bad idea to run `mdadm --zero-superblock` on every partition of the disk and added more troubles as I am now unable to do anything (except insulting myself).

`lsblk` returns this:

```
sdc        8:32   0   2,7T  0 disk  
├─sdc1     8:33   0 517,7M  0 part  
│ └─md11   9:11   0 516,7M  0 raid1 
├─sdc2     8:34   0 517,7M  0 part  
│ └─md12   9:12   0 516,7M  0 raid1 
├─sdc3     8:35   0   2,7T  0 part  
├─sdc4     8:36   0 517,7M  0 part  /media/myuser/2ed9e1b2-2659-4202-9066-bd3246353f1d
└─sdc5     8:37   0     8G  0 part  
  └─md15   9:15   0     8G  0 raid1 
md13       9:13   0     0B  0 md
```

The disk has indeed 5 partitions and I need to access `/dev/sdc3`. To my surprise, Ubuntu is able to mount `/dev/sdc4` without even asking.

When I run `lvm fullreport` I get:

```
lvm fullreport
  WARNING: wrong checksum 0 in mda header on /dev/sdc3 at 4096
  WARNING: wrong magic number in mda header on /dev/sdc3 at 4096
  WARNING: wrong version 0 in mda header on /dev/sdc3 at 4096
  WARNING: wrong start sector 0 in mda header on /dev/sdc3 at 4096
  WARNING: bad metadata header on /dev/sdc3 at 4096.
  WARNING: scanning /dev/sdc3 mda1 failed to read metadata summary.
  WARNING: repair VG metadata on /dev/sdc3 with vgck --updatemetadata.
  WARNING: scan failed to get metadata summary from /dev/sdc3 PVID A0oBICVnS2UPgax0Y8H2F5lgP2L3Xa3D
  Fmt  PV UUID                                DevSize PV         Maj Min PMdaFree  PMdaSize  PExtVsn 1st PE  PSize  PFree  Used Attr Allocatable Exported   Missing    PE  Alloc PV Tags #PMda #PMdaUse BA Start BA Size PInUse Duplicate
  lvm2 A0oBIC-VnS2-UPga-x0Y8-H2F5-lgP2-L3Xa3D  <2,72t /dev/sdc3  8   35         0         0        1   1,00m <2,72t <2,72t   0  ---                                      0     0             0        0       0       0                  
  Start SSize PV UUID                                LV UUID                               
      0     0 A0oBIC-VnS2-UPga-x0Y8-H2F5-lgP2-L3Xa3D
```

I have some things in `/etc/lvm` that seem backups, but I messed up enough already and I don't want to do more damage.

Searching in this and other forums I tried many things, most notably

```
mdadm --create --assume-clean /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc3 missing
```

but then if I try to mount the `/dev/md0` I get

```
mount: /mnt/1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

and `lvm fullreport` doesn't give any outputs.

Any help would be highly appreciated, I have the other raid disk that should contain the same info but before I mess that up as well I'd like to see if I can recover this one.

**EDIT 1**

Output of `blkid`:

```
/dev/sdc: PTUUID="170dad0b-6e63-4bbc-835e-9c7e901e3d4d" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sdc2: UUID="2d0918c5-2ae2-6736-cb3a-9dfb2f014dc0" UUID_SUB="7b071e98-21b9-2459-7b3d-232247796426" LABEL="home-x1-carbon:12" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="61b68a0d-0ebc-4379-9d8e-9694a0edc09d"
/dev/sdc5: UUID="2d279112-312e-1a89-d597-da4cc01c2a92" UUID_SUB="72243364-539b-6614-53c2-374e28a6a4e7" LABEL="home-x1-carbon:15" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="29af1fc5-57ab-4da4-ac38-d3d9955072b5"
/dev/sdc3: UUID="01f77d36-7ed1-f4be-6948-820e41b0956a" UUID_SUB="c78c6ff9-63bb-002f-93a4-c901bdb14307" LABEL="home-x1-carbon:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="4feebb7b-0a90-490c-a516-3fdca113592f"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="4a443aca-7fbe-197c-0bcb-72ec6c0c3ce0" UUID_SUB="55bf9203-a7ca-a8a3-4cdb-5cef7f12e54f" LABEL="home-x1-carbon:11" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="22efde15-2e64-4cf5-b220-21ee5c57aed2"
/dev/sdc4: UUID="2ed9e1b2-2659-4202-9066-bd3246353f1d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext3" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="d5ae2202-0f7b-4c30-b7c3-f9d84de4b14e"
```

`blkid /dev/md0` is empty.

**EDIT 2**

After trying this:

```
# mdadm --create --assume-clean /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc3 missing
mdadm: Note: this array has metadata at the start and
    may not be suitable as a boot device.  If you plan to
    store '/boot' on this device please ensure that
    your boot-loader understands md/v1.x metadata, or use
    --metadata=0.90
Continue creating array? y
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
```

`lsblk` now shows `/dev/md0`:

```
sdc        8:32   0   2,7T  0 disk  
├─sdc1     8:33   0 517,7M  0 part  
│ └─md11   9:11   0 516,7M  0 raid1 
├─sdc2     8:34   0 517,7M  0 part  
│ └─md12   9:12   0 516,7M  0 raid1 
├─sdc3     8:35   0   2,7T  0 part  
│ └─md0    9:0    0   2,7T  0 raid1 
├─sdc4     8:36   0 517,7M  0 part  /media/dani/2ed9e1b2-2659-4202-9066-bd3246353f1d
└─sdc5     8:37   0     8G  0 part  
  └─md15   9:15   0     8G  0 raid1 
md13       9:13   0     0B  0 md
```

but I still cannot mount it:

```
# mount /dev/md0 /mnt/1
mount: /mnt/1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `blkid` ? At least on all `sdc` partitions. - What is the output of `blkid` on `/dev/md0` ? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question with the requested info. thank you @hidigoudi

Comment: Thanks, have you successfully performed this command : `mdadm --create --assume-clean /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc3 missing` (without error) ? - You are able to mount the `/dev/sdc4` because it's an `ext3` partition, not a `md` device.

Comment: Do you see the `/dev/md0` in the `lsblk` output ? - If no, it's normal you are not able to mount it. - The `mdadm --zero-superblock` command **removes the metadata** that describes the raid array, you should always have the data themself.

Comment: yes, i performed the mdadm --create and got no errors: added the details above. I do see md0 in lsblk now.

Comment: Could you please update your post ? I do not see the `lsblk` on `/dev/md0`. - Furthermore, you should get a return on `blkid /dev/md0` now.

Comment: sorry I updated the comment before the post. It's there now.

Comment: Great thanks, do you have something with `blkid /dev/md0` ?

Comment: no `blkid /dev/md0` is still empty, although the drive woke up when I ran it

Comment: It seems like, the `/dev/md0` is a Physical Volume (LVM). Can you try to perform this command : `pvchange -ay /dev/md0`

Comment: it says the syntax is invalid: `No command with matching syntax recognised. ` I tried without the"y" flag as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150690/discussion-between-hidigoudi-and-daniele).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to recover your `RAID` array with the second drive. By performing `mdadm --zero-superblock` on all partitions, you destroyed all the `md superblock` with zeros. Below your `/dev/sdc3` you have a `LVM` tree with `VGs` / `LVs` which cannot be recovered with that drive.

If you connect the second drive, you should be able to `mount` your `LV` below the RAID device. Your architecture looks like (**based on our discussion**) :

```
└─sdc3                      8:51   0  2.7T  0 part   
  └─md1                     9:1    0  2.7T  0 raid1 
      ├─vg_lv0 252:1    0 27,9G  0 lvm
      └─vg_lv1 252:2    0  2.7T  0 lvm
```

With this above schema (`lsblk` output), the `blkid` output is :

```
/dev/mapper/vg_lv1: LABEL="nas-qnap" UUID="75debd37-77c6-4f98-a6b6-8acc2a9f141f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
```

As you can see, it's an `ext4` partition. You should be able to mount it with :

```
mount /dev/vg_lv1 /mnt
mount /dev/mapper/vg_lv1 /mnt
```

However, it's not enough at this point. You have a `degraded` array (`mdadm --detail /dev/md1`). To recover a `clean` state, you need to connect your broken drive and add the respective partitions on the different `md devices`. Once both drives connected, you should have the broken one like that :

```
sdc        8:32   0   2,7T  0 disk  
├─sdc1     8:33   0 517,7M  0 part  
│ └─md11   9:11   0 516,7M  0 raid1 
├─sdc2     8:34   0 517,7M  0 part  
│ └─md12   9:12   0 516,7M  0 raid1 
├─sdc3     8:35   0   2,7T  0 part  
│ └─md0    9:0    0   2,7T  0 raid1 
├─sdc4     8:36   0 517,7M  0 part  /media/dani/2ed9e1b2-2659-4202-9066-bd3246353f1d
└─sdc5     8:37   0     8G  0 part  
  └─md15   9:15   0     8G  0 raid1
```

As you can see above, you have **4** `md devices`. Here is the list according to the above schema :

- /dev/md11
- /dev/md12
- /dev/md15
- /dev/md0

The `/dev/sdc4` is only an `ext3` files system partition. Before adding those array, you need to stop them like this :

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md11
mdadm --stop /dev/md12
mdadm --stop /dev/md15
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
```

Then you should be able to add them in the correct array with this :

```
mdadm /dev/mdX --add /dev/sdY1
mdadm /dev/mdX --add /dev/sdY2
mdadm /dev/mdX --add /dev/sdY3
mdadm /dev/mdX --add /dev/sdY5
```

The `X` corresponds to the `md device` on the **clean drive**. The `Y` corresponds to the **broken drive**. With `RAID 1`, it should be "easy" to match partitions as it's a **mirroring**.

**Assuming**, your clean drive looks like :

```
sdb 8:16 0 2,7T 0 disk
  ├─sdb1 8:17 0 517,7M 0 part
  │ └─md9 9:9 0 517,6M 0 raid1
  ├─sdb2 8:18 0 517,7M 0 part
  │ └─md256 9:256 0 0B 0 md
  ├─sdb3 8:19 0 2,7T 0 part
  │ └─md1 9:1 0 2,7T 0 raid1
  │   ├─vg_lv0
  │   │ 253:0 0 27,9G 0 lvm
  │   └─vg_lv1
  │      253:1 0 2,7T 0 lvm
  ├─sdb4 8:20 0 517,7M 0 part
  └─sdb5 8:21 0 8G 0 part
    └─md322 9:322 0 0B 0 md
```

The commands to add should be :

```
mdadm /dev/md9 --add /dev/sdc1
mdadm /dev/md256 --add /dev/sdc2
mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sdc3
mdadm /dev/md322 --add /dev/sdc5
```

You can consult the `resync` speed and time remaining of your arrays with :

```
watch -n0.5 cat /proc/mdstat
```